# Join Apple Dev team w/ just an Apple ID or is Enrolling Required?

Tags: ios, apple-developer

Can I be invited to join another team's Apple Developer Account with just the creation of an Apple ID, or do I need to explicitly enroll in the Apple Developer Program after creating said Apple ID? I've created a new Apple ID account but I'm not receiving any invite email from said team and I can't find any clarification around this.

Comment: I think it's funny how this question was downvoted, yet every answer given below contradicts one another.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can be invited by the team which got enrolled in the Apple developer program and you don't need to be enrolled in the program to get invited..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to explicitly enrol in the Apple Developer Program because if both have Apple developer account then you invite to join another team's Apple Developer Account.

Answer (score 1):

You can be invited by another team's enrolled Apple Developer Account, and You are not needed to enroll Apple Developer Program just to join as a team member for an already enrolled account.

However, there is some problem around invitation e-mails being sent. I faced same problem when I used my company ID for Apple ID.

But when I used my g-mail ID for Apple ID, The invitation mail came quickly. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Enroll Apple Developer Program, After that you can Invite People.
And You can be invited by the team(Only if that team is already Enroll).

You can also refer this two links [Enroll Account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/) & [Adding a new Admin to your developer.apple.com account](https://www.mobiloud.com/help/knowledge-base/adding-a-new-admin-to-your-developer-apple-com-account/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can be invited to other peoples developer team. Without Needing to pay the $99 fee. However, you will not be able to publish and tests apps on real devices and you will be restricted to the features that Apple provides for its developers - such as creating signing certificates and adding push notification capabilities within your app.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I finally figured this out.  In order to be able to successfully process the e-mail invite, you have to be logged into the account for which you received the invite.  If you are logged in there, then when clicking on the link in the e-mail invitation, you will be prompted to join the organization.  I am not sure why you are not receiving the e-mail at all, but that could be something just blocking the e-mail from arriving.